# Using ComposeList to Generate Pure Functions for Iteration

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to use functional programming in place of imperative programming. One of the things I would like to do is iteration. As an example, to try to convert the following loop

```
x0 = [1,2];

for i = 1:4
y1 = [x0(1)*x0(2),x0(2)/x0(1)];
y2 = [y1(1)/y2(2),5];
y3 = [(y2(1)+y2(2))^2, 1 + y2(1)];
y4 = [y3(1)/4, y3(2)/6];
x0 = y4;
end
```

The analogous functional approach is

```
step4 = Function[{#[[1]]/4, #[[2]]/6}];
step3 = Function[{(#[[1]] + #[[2]])^2, 1 + #[[1]]}];
step2 = Function[{#[[1]]/#[[2]], 5}];
step1 = Function[{#[[1]]*#[[2]], #[[2]]/#[[1]]}];
total = Composition[step4, step3, step2, step1];
(* alternatively, Function[step4[step3[step2[step1[#]]]]] *)
NestList[total, {2., 3.}, 4]
```

For the purpose of debugging, I would like to use `ComposeList` to know, giving an initial starting value, what the value at a given step would be. However, while `Composition` can be used to generate a pure function, `ComposeList` must be given a formal parameter. For the use above, with functions defined with list inputs, I have to put in a list of formal parameters like `{x,y}`, which prevents subsequent use with functions like `NestList`. For example,

```
all = ComposeList[{step1, step2, step3, step4}, {x, y}]
uptostep2 = all[[2]];
```

Is there a way to create pure functions using `ComposeList` or another method to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

What about `FoldList[Composition, {step1, step2, step3, step4}]`?